# for loop elimination

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to use the [indices trick](http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks%3aindices) to eliminate `for` loops in my C++11 program (similar to forced `-funroll-loops`).

Here's an example:

```
template<unsigned...> struct indices
{
};

template<unsigned M, unsigned... Is> struct indices_gen
  : indices_gen<M - 1, M - 1, Is...>
{
};

template<unsigned... Is> struct indices_gen<0, Is...> : indices<Is...>
{
};

template <typename T>
struct example
{
  example()
  {
    assign(indices_gen<3>(), 0);
  }

  template<unsigned... Is, typename U>
  void assign(indices<Is...>, U value)
  {
    [](...){}((array[Is] = value)...);
  }

  T array[3];
};

int main()
{
  example<int> ex;
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to create an `indices_gen<S,E>`, from start index `S` to end index `E`? Can you please show how?

Comment: Of course. I'm not sure what the actual question is. Just do it.

Comment: Well, I don't really know how :) Hints?

Comment: Well, you currently have the end condition hardcoded at 0: `struct indices_gen< 0 , Is...> :`. Similarly, the step size is hardcoded at 1: `: indices_gen<M - 1, M - 1, Is...>`

Comment: Thanks Xeo and Pawel, I wonder if eliminating `for` loop might be considered abuse of language features :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ( http://liveworkspace.org/code/e65a81d0d3e9b17692713fd3e9d681f5 ):

```
template<unsigned...> struct indices {};

template<unsigned S, unsigned E, unsigned... Is> struct indices_gen
  : indices_gen<S, E-1, E-1, Is...>
{};

template<unsigned S, unsigned... Is> struct indices_gen<S, S, Is...> : indices<Is...>
{};
```

Working example: http://liveworkspace.org/code/3d0ba21cc637a61c3e63d2db002f87af

***Edit*** : Check Xeo's comment. Above example don't check if `S < E`, so it can go bad if you make a mistake. This (Xeo's code) will return a compiler error in such case: http://liveworkspace.org/code/81205e13334e89537bdc0b79b3ba56fc

Comment: Well done, although this has the problem that if `S > E` you get your compiler blown up thanks to endless recursion, so I recommend a `static_assert` (something like [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/81205e13334e89537bdc0b79b3ba56fc), the `inherit_if` is there to stop the recursive template instantiations). And maybe you should mention that this now denotes a half-open range `[S,E)`.

Comment: It was `[S,E]`, but it was awkard to use it in example. It still is closed in the the first link though. Also you are totally right about `S > E`.