# iteration direction on an array

Tags: c++, arrays, cpu-cache

Say we have two arrays `a` and `b` of a fundamental type (say, a `float`) and we need to calculate `a[i] + b[i]` for every valid index `i`, as well as store the result. What is the best way to iterate over the arrays to maximize cache hits? Is it front-to-back, back-to-front or something else?

Comment: To start with, don't use plain arrays, use either [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you know the size at compilation time, or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I would say, code your iteration "the most normal way" and let the compiler do its job;)

Comment: If you care about this, you should have some benchmarks set up.

Comment: On a modern CPU difference is usually negligible and compilers are often smarter than you at optimizing. Unless you have a factual reason (i.e. you have profiled your code and came to the conclusion that you have a bottleneck), you shouldn't be caring about this.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I am using the indices trick to eliminate for/while loops and my compiler is not smart enough to figure out what I am doing is actually an unwrapped loop.

Comment: What "indices trick"? Does that result in a measurable performance hit?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo It is a [way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794114/for-loop-elimination) to force loop unwrapping, even though the compiler can do it itself sometimes. As far as measurements are concerned, I am not proficient enough to do them, I'd just like a rule of thumb, what is better, since I can unwrap in an arbitrary way. I could even do random order.

Comment: Why not simply use `-funroll-loops` and `-funroll-all-loops` and leave the decision to your compiler? Refrain from that kind of overcomplication, unless you have a strong reason for using it. However, if you cannot measure performance hit, how can you be sure that your "optimizations" didn't slow down the computation?

Comment: What do you mean by store the result?  Do you men c[i] = a[i] + b[i] or do you mean sum += a[i] + b[i].  If you're doing the first case then don't think about it any further: your compiler will do the best job.  If you're doing the second case (a reduction). Then you need to unroll you4 loop.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo it's just a thing I have. The compiler is smart, but it has it's limits, or it would do the programming for us.

Comment: You are completely wrong if you think you can master the pipeline and cache of a modern CPU architecture. Write code you can read and understand and let the compiler do its work.

Comment: Also, you don't seem to understand what the role of a compiler is. It cannot translate your thoughts into programs, but it can well translate a machine parseable representation (i.e. source code) into executable programs. In a certain sense, compilers do part of your work. Or have you ever allocated a stack frame by hand? Or reordered instructions to maximize pipeline throughput?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I am just after a rule-of-thumb. The compiler can reorder instructions in my unrolled loop as much as it like. But if loop unrolling via the indices trick is harmful, then please provide an example.

Comment: There is no rule of thumb, get over it. Learn how to profile your code (it's not difficult), implement it in the straightforward way, try `-O3` optimizations and time it. Overcomplicating source code is always harmful, as it introduces further points of failure and makes more difficult for other people to understand it.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo There are rules of thumb, 2 posters say front-to-back.

Answer (score 1):

In order to utilize the cache pre-fetch capability you need to read the arrays from front to back sequentially.

Furthermore, the arrays should be SSE aligned (16 byte). Even more important is that the items (e.g. floats) will be aligned on their size (4 bytes for floats). This is important so data will not cross cache lines (slower read).

After the arrays are aligned, you can use SSE/AVX to read, add and store the results doing 4 or 8 operations in a single instruction.

**Edit:**
You can read more on cache prefetching [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/08/24/what-you-need-to-know-about-prefetching) and in depth description in the [Intel SW Developer Manual](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: Note that the compiler (GCC and Clang at least) might optimize using  SSE instruction set if possible.

Comment: Depending on optimization level, of course. Hence the importance of the alignment.

Comment: @egur can you provide a source for the front-to-back rule of thumb? I could even do random order.

Comment: Front to back means starting with array index zero and moving sequentially up. 2 trivial for source code...

Comment: @egur I meant the source(s) (sites, books, ...) of the assertion, not source code :)

Comment: According to *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual* (June 2011), Section 2.2.4.3 Prefetch Logic, the stream prefetcher for the Core microarchitecture supports both forward and backward streams, though there are 12 forward and only 4 backward entries (each of which covers a 4KiB page); so clearly forward streams are *preferred* but backward streams are also supported.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of operation you should use the auto-vectorization of your compiler. Iterate small `i` to large `i`. Also, the answer depends on what you mean by "store the result" and the number `n` of items items you are going to iterate over.

If you mean `c[i] = a[i] + b[i]` and `n` is not too small then your compiler's auto-vectorizer will optimize this best without any more changes. Even MSVC will get that one correct (at least for SSE). Your compiler will have to do some adjustments for n not a multiple of 4 (or 8 for AVX) and alignment but this cost will be amortized across n and this overhead will have a negligible effect except for small `n`. If `n` is small then you might want to consider alignment.  How small is small has to be determined but I would guess it's much less than 100.

If you mean `sum + = a[i] + b[i]`, a reduction, then you do need to think about this. This has a dependency chain so you need to unroll your loop [3-10 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090873/loop-unrolling-to-achieve-maximum-throughput-with-ivy-bridge-and-haswell). Additionally, you need to use a relaxed floating point model since [floating point arithmetic is not associative and the auto-vectorization won't kick in without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378889/auto-vectorization-not-working/23382578#23382578) so add `-ffast-math` to GCC (`/fp:fast` to MSVC). If you unroll the loop and use a a relaxed floating point model then GCC, ICC, Clang, and MSVC should auto-vectorize your reduction efficiently.

Comment: What happens, if you unroll "infinitely", that is, eliminate the loop entirely?

Comment: @user1095108, depends on what you’re doing.  If n is really small then it may make sense to fully unroll. You have to try and see. Keep in mind the size of the code cache (32kB). Don't be surprised if the right optimization changes for each CPU set.